# Getting model.id from backbone.js collection create success call using Tastypie?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I used to be able to get my model.id from a newly created backbone collection.create call via the following example code:

```
OPTS['success'] = function( response, model, options ){
                model.id
}

SOMECOLLECTION.create(json_attributes,OPTS)
```

This no longer works in v1.1.2. Anyone know what is going on here? It now returns an array of objects. I am using Django-Tastypie to create my RESTful urls.

Comment: Can you post the text of the request and response? I would bet the id is not in the return, or your idAttribute isn't set to the same thing as the id that is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem today, it was I was using namespaces with the tastypie urls:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)))
```

was changed to this

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls),namespace='api'))
```

for unit testing purposes, but this created an issue with reverse calls in the tastypie framework itself, and in the end it changed the response.location header to not include the url to the actual model itself after the create (POST) call was made. Remove the namespace fixed this problem